# UI switch save position NSSUser defaults only works if manually switched

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have five switches. The position is saved using `NSSUserDeafults`.

If a `UISwitch` is switched `.on` others go to the off position.  All the switches respect the users choice of position and save correctly.

The problem is the `UISwitch` position will only save if its  manually switched, and not when `.on = NO` is called by the sender.  This means if all the switches have been set to `on` at any point when the view is load they will all be `.on` until another switch is set off and on again.

The switches move over to the off position, but are not saved  (unless done manually)

```
- (IBAction)plainToggled:(id)sender {



if (sender == _plainToggle) {

    _curvesToggle.on = NO;
    _cloudsToggle.on = NO;
    _circlesToggle.on = NO;
    _fadeToggle.on = NO;

    BOOL mySwitchValuePlain = [ sender isOn ];
    NSString *tmpStringPlain = mySwitchValuePlain ? @"1" : @"-1" ;
    NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDPlain = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [myNSUDPlain setBool:TRUE forKey:@"switchBOOLPlain"];
    [ myNSUDPlain setObject:tmpStringPlain forKey: @"mySwitchValueKeyPlain" ];
    [ myNSUDPlain synchronize ];

    //save a key to read switch state in another view
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsPlain = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaultsPlain setBool:self.plainToggle.on forKey:@"switchPlain"];
    [userDefaultsPlain synchronize];

    }


}

 - (IBAction)curvesToggled:(id)sender {


if (sender == _curvesToggle) {

    _cloudsToggle.on = NO;
    _circlesToggle.on = NO;
    _fadeToggle.on = NO;
    _plainToggle.on = NO;

    BOOL mySwitchValueCurves = [ sender isOn ];
    NSString *tmpStringCurves = mySwitchValueCurves ? @"1" : @"-1" ;
    NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDCurves = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [myNSUDCurves setBool:TRUE forKey:@"switchBOOLCurves"];
    [ myNSUDCurves setObject:tmpStringCurves forKey: @"mySwitchValueKeyCurves" ];
    [ myNSUDCurves synchronize ];

    //save a key to read switch state in another view
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsCurves = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaultsCurves setBool:self.curvesToggle.on forKey:@"switchCurves"];
    [userDefaultsCurves synchronize];

   }


}
 - (IBAction)cloudsToggled:(id)sender {



if (sender == _cloudsToggle) {

    _curvesToggle.on = NO;
    _circlesToggle.on = NO;
    _fadeToggle.on = NO;
    _plainToggle.on = NO;


    BOOL mySwitchValueClouds = [ sender isOn ];
    NSString *tmpStringClouds = mySwitchValueClouds ? @"1" : @"-1" ;
    NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDClouds = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [myNSUDClouds setBool:TRUE forKey:@"switchBOOLClouds"];
    [ myNSUDClouds setObject:tmpStringClouds forKey: @"mySwitchValueKeyClouds" ];
    [ myNSUDClouds synchronize ];

    //save a key to read switch state in another view
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsClouds = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaultsClouds setBool:self.cloudsToggle.on forKey:@"switchClouds"];
    [userDefaultsClouds synchronize];

    }


}

 - (IBAction)circlesToggled:(id)sender {



if (sender == _circlesToggle) {

    _curvesToggle.on = NO;
    _cloudsToggle.on = NO;
    _fadeToggle.on = NO;
    _plainToggle.on = NO;

    BOOL mySwitchValueCircles = [ sender isOn ];
    NSString *tmpStringCircles = mySwitchValueCircles ? @"1" : @"-1" ;
    NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDCircles = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [myNSUDCircles setBool:TRUE forKey:@"switchBOOLCircles"];
    [ myNSUDCircles setObject:tmpStringCircles forKey: @"mySwitchValueKeyCircles" ];
    [ myNSUDCircles synchronize ];

    //save a key to read switch state in another view
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsCircles = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaultsCircles setBool:self.circlesToggle.on forKey:@"switchCircles"];
    [userDefaultsCircles synchronize];

  }


}
- (IBAction)fadeToggled:(id)sender {



if (sender == _fadeToggle) {

    _curvesToggle.on = NO;
    _cloudsToggle.on = NO;
    _circlesToggle.on = NO;
    _plainToggle.on = NO;

    BOOL mySwitchValueFade = [ sender isOn ];
    NSString *tmpStringFade = mySwitchValueFade ? @"1" : @"-1" ;
    NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDFade = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [myNSUDFade setBool:TRUE forKey:@"switchBOOLFade"];
    [ myNSUDFade setObject:tmpStringFade forKey: @"mySwitchValueKeyFade" ];
    [ myNSUDFade synchronize ];

    //save a key to read switch state in another view
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsFade = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaultsFade setBool:self.fadeToggle.on forKey:@"switchFade"];
    [userDefaultsFade synchronize];

  }




}
```

reading switch state in `viewDidLoad`

```
//switch value for plain cert
NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDPlain = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *tmpStringPlain =  [ myNSUDPlain stringForKey: @"switchPlain"];
BOOL mySwitchValuePlain = YES;  // or DEFAULT_VALUE
if (tmpStringPlain != nil) {
    mySwitchValuePlain = ( [ tmpStringPlain intValue ] == 1 );
}
[_plainToggle setOn: mySwitchValuePlain];



//switch value for curves cert
NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDCurves = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *tmpStringCurves =  [ myNSUDCurves stringForKey: @"switchCurves"];
BOOL mySwitchValueCurves = NO;  // or DEFAULT_VALUE
if (tmpStringCurves != nil) {
    mySwitchValueCurves = ( [ tmpStringCurves intValue ] == 1 );
}
[_curvesToggle setOn: mySwitchValueCurves];

//switch value for clouds cert
NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDClouds = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *tmpStringClouds =  [ myNSUDClouds stringForKey: @"switchClouds"];
BOOL mySwitchValueClouds = NO;  // or DEFAULT_VALUE
if (tmpStringClouds != nil) {
    mySwitchValueClouds = ( [ tmpStringClouds intValue ] == 1 );
}
[_cloudsToggle setOn: mySwitchValueClouds];

//switch value for circles cert
NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDCircles = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *tmpStringCircles =  [ myNSUDCircles stringForKey: @"switchCircles"];
BOOL mySwitchValueCircles = NO;  // or DEFAULT_VALUE
if (tmpStringCircles != nil) {
    mySwitchValueCircles = ( [ tmpStringCircles intValue ] == 1 );
}
[_circlesToggle setOn: mySwitchValueCircles];

//switch value for fade cert
NSUserDefaults  *myNSUDFade = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *tmpStringFade =  [ myNSUDFade stringForKey: @"switchFade"];
BOOL mySwitchValueFade = NO;  // or DEFAULT_VALUE
if (tmpStringFade != nil) {
    mySwitchValueFade = ( [ tmpStringFade intValue ] == 1 );
}
[_fadeToggle setOn: mySwitchValueFade];



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow MVC paradigm. You should not store state in a UI control. Instead, set UI control to match the state of your model/data and have your UI control change the state of your model/data.

One simple way to accomplish this is to have a Boolean variable or property for each switch with the current state (YES or NO).

These variable/property values can easily be stored and retrieved from `NSUserDefaults`.

In your `viewWillAppear`, you set the value of the UI controls based on the variables.

Then, when users change the value of a switch, set the value of the variable/property in the `IBAction` method.

Now, your initial view displays properly. Even if the values are changed from a different view controller, your switches will still display the proper value.

Comment: Yep going with the Boolean variable aproach

Answer (score 1):

Target&selector of event `UIControlEventValueChanged` is not called when you set the value at code. Also, you are not saving the states of other switches so you'll have several switches saved at `On` position. Finally, you can merge the action methods as you are already doing `sender` recognition.

Comment: Lesson learnt, thanks valueChanged not being called when in code.   Regarding merge action methods, are you referring to saving in the off position can be merged here?

Comment: @JSA986 By merging I meant to replace 5 `IBAction`s with one. But you need to reset the other switches saved state as well, for example save  `NO` for all switches at the beginning and `YES` at the end for the one that was pressed. Also, you are better to use `boolForKey:` and `setBool:forKey:` to read&write bool values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5 switches, but only one can be on at any given time, and all the others will always be off, why have 5 variables when only one can do it?  Have an int or w/e stored in NSUserDefaults.  When making the view, check what the stored int is and set all the switches off except the appropriate one.  When a switch is toggled, change the stored value and toggle all the other switches programmatically.
If it's possible to have all switches set to off (with none on) have the 0 or -1 value be for that case.

As was pointed out in other answers, UIControlEventValueChanged is not called when you set a value programmatically.  If you insist on having 5 different variables for your switches, when any one is switched, you'll have to programmatically switch all the others (which you already do) and also set all the other's bools.

Regardless, UI elements should always refer to an independent variable for their state rather than controlling their state themselves.  However you do it, changing this will fix the issue.